# ERROR 12545 : Connect failed because target host or object doesn't exist while trying to connect sqlplus

Tags: database, oracle, ubuntu, oracle11g, sqlplus

I want to install oracle instant client but I have been stuck while I was trying to remote DB. I always got error ORA-12545, but my oracle DB is active and works fine.. i already started listener and config /etc/host on both side.

Here's my tnsnames.ora configuration on Oracle Database server:

```
ROLFSAN =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = ullabritta)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = rolf)
    )
  )
```

and here's my tnsname.ora configuration on oracle instant :

```
SVEN = -- i give this name as i wish, there's no sven on oracle database
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = ullabritta)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = rolf)
    )
  )
```

did i do something wrong? or there's specific configuration on oracle database server??

Answer (score 0):

Use the IP address, not the hostname. Oracle client uses DNS to resolve the name, and may not use the hosts file.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answers. I change it to ip address it's still doesn't work, but if i login with this 'sqlplus user/password@ipaddress:1521/rolf' it works fine.

by any change do you know whats wrong? because i need to make sure a TNS Listener and an Oracle instance are available for connection for monitoring oracle by ODBC via zabbix.

Comment: Are you sure that the system is using the tnsnames.ora file entry you think it is? Use the methods described by Bjarte Brandt, or set the TRACE_LEVEL_CLIENT parameter in sqlnet.ora (https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NETRF/sqlnet.htm#NETRF250) to "SUPPORT" to confirm.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the connect description in one line and verify

```
sqlplus user/pass@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=ullabritta)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=rolf)))
```

Next, make sure your client is picking up the tnsnames.ora file utilizing strace. strace will output all system-calls your client is doing.

```
strace sqlplus user/pass@TNS_ALIAS
```

You can place the tnsnames.ora file anywhere you like on the filesystem. The environment variable TNS_ADMIN overrides any default location.

```
cat > tnsnames.ora <<EOF
MY_ALIAS=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=ullabritta)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=rolf)))
EOF
export TNS_ADMIN=./
sqlplus user/pass@MY_ALIAS
```

Best of luck!